# 3 output MOSFET? does such thing exists?

Tags: mosfet

I need to control 30 high Current LED's, the issue is I don't want to have 30 MOSFETs, is there any way around this dilemma? any help will be appreciated, I am aware of the CSD17313Q2, but not sure if it has separated outputs, it appears to have 2 gate pins?

Comment: You can certainly find parts that have two MOSFETs in the same package, and a few that have quads, but those are generally (the quads) not high power parts. Can you share an overall system design? Perhaps we can find another solution with more information. Do you need them because of power reasons? Or for individual control of LEDs reasons?

Comment: That's just a single MOSFET- look for MOSFET arrays. Eg. STL15DN4F5 dual. If current requirements are relatively modest consider DMOS power shift registers eg. TPIC series.

Comment: (1) The answer depends on how you want to control 30 LEDs. Each one individually?  How much current?  (2) [CSD17313Q2](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd17313q2.pdf) has got a single gate pin (although there exists such a thing as [dual gate MOSFET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#Dual-gate_MOSFET)).

Comment: they are 3 watt RGB's its a low current application, not exactly on the current draw but its not a great deal. Upverter must be wrong.

Comment: I am using them because I need to control 10RGB Leds, the power draw is to much for the controller, nearly 100W about 90 or so, I think, the controller would just melt.

Comment: If you could run the LEDs as a 5 X 6 array that would take only  11 MOSFETs, and if you could run them at five times their normal current at a 20% duty cycle you wouldn't have to sacrifice brightness.  Can you post the LED data sheet (best) or a link to it (OK), please?

Comment: Linear Tech makes an IC, the LT3746, that is controllable with SPI with a built in DC-DC converter that has 30 or so controllable ports, I can't remember what the current was but its quite high. You also have PWM control and can control the brightness.

Answer (score 1):

This is exceedingly driven by what you need to do, control-wise. If you just need to drive 30, **one** MOSFET and enough voltage will get you there - perhaps 3 MOSFETs since you mention in a comment that they are RGB. Stack them all in series, drive the desired current at the required voltage, done.

If you need to drive **each** of 30 RGB **individually**, then you're looking at **90 outputs** you need to control.

Quick look with still having no real data on your parts/needs, something like SLA5085 & SLA5086 seems to combine power and 5 individually controllable FETs in a package (common Source) - but you'll still need 18 of them to drive RGB.

Comment: drive 30 individually.